# Connection between AngularJS and postgres

Tags: angularjs

I am implementing a single page application in AngularJS and I am using apache tomact server. Now I am trying to connect AngularJS with PostgreSQL.I have installed PostgreSQL driver by using node js in the root folder of web application and also included PostgreSQL jar file in lib folder of apache tomcat. But when I am trying to run the application on server then it showing an error " Module name "pg" has not been loaded yet for context: `_. Use require([])` "
How can I resolve this error??

Comment: You seem deeply confused. There is no way an angular application can connect to postgreSQL. The angular app will use $http to send HTTP requests to your Java webapp deployed in Tomcat, and the Java webapp will connect to PostgreSQL, and send back results in JSON format to the browser. You don't need a NodeJS driver for Postgres. Angular runs in the browser, not under NodeJS. And Tomcat web applications are written in Java, not in JavaScript.

Comment: what procedure should I follow to connect postgres with angularjs?? so that I can run web application on tomcat server.

Comment: Have you read my comment? You can't connect postgres to angular. Search how to access a database from a Java webapp deployed in Tomcat. AngularJS is completely irrelevant here.